# How can I make OnDrawGizmos and OnDrawGizmosSelected functions to run the code inside with a button click?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CurvedLinePoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector] public bool showGizmo = true;
    [HideInInspector] public float gizmoSize = 0.1f;
    [HideInInspector] public Color gizmoColor = new Color(1, 0, 0, 0.5f);

    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        if (ResetLineRendererPositions.hasReseted == false)
        {
            if (showGizmo == true)
            {
                Gizmos.color = gizmoColor;

                Gizmos.DrawSphere(this.transform.position, gizmoSize);
            }
        }
    }

    //update parent line when this point moved
    void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        if (ResetLineRendererPositions.hasReseted == false)
        {
            CurvedLineRenderer curvedLine = this.transform.parent.GetComponent<CurvedLineRenderer>();

            if (curvedLine != null)
            {
                curvedLine.Update();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I created two scripts one is editor type with two buttons. One to reset the linerenderer positions and one to generate the positions :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ResetLineRendererPositions : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public static bool hasReseted = false;

    public void ResetLinerendererPositions()
    {
        lineRenderer.positionCount = 0;
        hasReseted = true;
    }

    public void GenerateLineRendererPositions()
    {
        hasReseted = false;
    }
}
```

And

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(ResetLineRendererPositions))]
public class ResetLineRendererPositionsButton : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        ResetLineRendererPositions myScript = (ResetLineRendererPositions)target;
        if (GUILayout.Button("Reset Linerenderer Positions"))
        {
            myScript.ResetLinerendererPositions();
        }

        GUILayout.Space(30);

        if (GUILayout.Button("Generate Linerenderer Positions"))
        {
            myScript.GenerateLineRendererPositions();
        }
    }
}
```

The buttons are working the problem is when I click on the button "Generate Linerenderer Positions" then I have to select the linerenderer object in the hierarchy to make it take affect and draw the gizmos.

I want that when I click the "Generate Linerenderer Positions" button it will automatic run the code in the OnDrawGizmos and OnDrawGizmosSelected functions.

Comment: Tried to add [ExecuteInEditMode] in the top of the CurvedLinePoint script but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The buttons are working the problem is when I click on the button "Generate Linerenderer Positions" then I have to select the linerenderer object in the hierarchy to make it take affect and draw the gizmos.

`OnDrawGizmosSelected()` is only called by the Editor when you select that object or one of its parents. Although you could have your button call `OnDrawGizmosSelected()`, that's not what `OnDrawGizmosSelected()` is for.

Also, `OnDrawGizmos()`/`OnDrawGizmosSelected()` are only intended for drawing Gizmos and other Unity Editor markup. You should not be calling other code, such as `curvedLine.Update()`, from within either of these functions.

It seems like you should have the GUI button call `curvedLine.Update()`, rather than involving `OnDrawGizmosSelected()`.